# Recursive adb pull

Tags: adb, usb, backup, file-transfer

How to copy a whole directory (and all of its content recursively) over USB with `adb pull`? For instance to backup the SD card.

Attempt:

```
$ adb pull /sdcard backup
failed to copy '/sdcard' to 'backup': Is a directory
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The trick is to add `/.` to the name of the folder you want to copy:

```
adb pull /sdcard/. backup
```

This copies the whole directory recursively.