# recursive adb pull a directory using $EXTERNAL_STORAGE parameter

Tags: adb

I wish to pull a directory from an Android device which contains screenshots, reason why, is that I don't know the name of these screenshots to pull them 1 by 1, so pulling the directory seemed a better idea.

My command is,

```
adb pull "\\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/screen/" .
```

However I get the error,

```
remote object '\\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/screen/' does not exist
```

I have tried with and without the trailing '/' but both same error message, and I have verified that 'screen' does actually exist.

My question, is it even possible to pull a directory, as opposed to individual files, and if so, what am I doing incorrect?

EDIT:
I have read a similar issue, but my device still shows the error above rather than "Is a directory"
[Recursive adb pull](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87326/recursive-adb-pull?rq=1)

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225750/105083) by Gilles. It should help in using that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the screenshots are getting saved in external SD card then I believe external SD card is set as default write-disk. In that case, you can do,

```
adb pull /sdcard/{YOUR_DIR}/ {TARGET_DIR}
```

I use my custom alias named `adbshots` which is,

```
/usr/bin/adb pull /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/ /root
```

Comment: thanks, this did work. I was attempting to utilise the EXTERNAL_STORAGE parameter but its fine. On further thought, I guess its that adb pull does not initialise local parameters like adb shell does; therefore it doesn't work.

Comment: Your $EXTERNAL_STORAGE seems to be a variable initialized in your OS. It needs to be a path like `/XYZ/ABC/` -- the *nix way which ADB can use to trace the source dir in Android. While the question is solved, you may still troubleshoot the issue. See what is the value of $EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: $EXTERNAL_STORAGE points to the path of the external sdcard on the device. 
    
adb shell echo \\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE

\/storage/emulated/legacy

I just wanted to use that to find te location of the ext sd card, I was unaware that /sdcard/ was basically a pointer to what I was attempting

Comment: It is true that $EXTERNAL_STORAGE points to the external SD card but the variable has its scope inside the Android. When you use it with adb pull, then ADB treats it as a variable defined in the host system, ultimately, the command would fail if the variable is not defined or initialized explicitly in your host or the current shell session.

Answer (score -1):

try this. This should work.

adb pull /sdcard/screen/

Comment: Typical usage of `adb pull` goes by `adb pull <remote> <local>`. Please explain how your command is relevant for the objective OP wants to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that point is true that `<local>` is not needed if you want the source to be copied into the directory from where the shell is invoked from. But in your command, `/sdcard/.` is `<remote>` and `screen` is `<local>`. It would fail for sure.

Comment: Firelord Thanks for reply it was a mistake.I have corrected it.