# adb pull not honoring trailing slash, push ignores permissions

Tags: adb

If I use

```
adb push mydir/ /sdcard/Documents/
```

the result is as expected: all files from within `mydir/` end up inside `/sdcard/Documents/` (just the permissions are not kept, even not when using `-a`; on the internal sdcard everything is turned into `0660` while on the external sdcard everything is set to `0771` – which might be a limitation of sdcardfs as not even `chmod 0764` on the device has any effect). But the other direction is weird: using

```
adb pull /sdcard/Documents/ mydir/
```

results in the files showing up inside `mydir/Documents/`, which is rather very unexpected. I've played with all combinations of trailing slashes (including without any trailing slashes), no dice. Even tried different versions of `adb` (thinking the one used might have a bug). Same happens when using the external sdcard, so it's not the symlink (`/sdcard -> /storage/self/primary`) fooling it.

So any clue what could be wrong here? When I search on the net, all findings suggest it should work as I expect, but it somehow does not. **How would I need to adjust above `adb pull` command so all files from inside `/sdcard/Documents/` show up locally inside `mydir/`, but not the `Documents/` directory itself as subdir?** And: **How to keep permissions as they are?**

Comment: adb for some reason doesn't accept wildcards, though they should be processed from shell. nice find for the dot trick ;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/23242004

Comment: @alecxs credits for the dot-findings go to Nicolas (see the link). And as for permissions: for the example given I agree the FS is the cause. It's nasty though, and one must be aware of it. If you use a spare old device for backups that way and rely on the permissions to stay correct, this could be quite an issue. I've not tested how it would work with ADB running in root mode and the target being e.g. inside `/data` (say, `/data/data/mybackups`).

Comment: you could use tar `adb shell "tar -ch sdcard | gzip" > sdcard_backup.tar.gz`

Comment: @alecxs Nope, I should not. That might be a work-around for copying, but doesn't work with `rsync` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Took me almost a full day to find a partly solution rather by accident. While adding a wildcard (`adb pull /sdcard/Documents/*`) just leads to an error, adding a dot leads to the intended result:

```
adb pull /sdcard/Documents/. mydir/
```

has the **files** (and sub-directories) from within `/sdcard/Documents` showing up in `mydir/`, but not the `Documents` directory itself ([found here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/87327/16575) when writing my question and checking suggested "similar questions").

Also helpful in this context: `adb push` supports a `--sync` option (to only transfer newer and updated files) – and while not documented, `adb pull` <s>supports it as well</s>¹ (but needs `-a` in addition to keep timestamps intact). So the rather complicated work-arounds or external tools [of the past](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40459/16575) are no longer needed.

```
adb push --sync local/ device/
# adb pull --sync -a device/. local/
```

No `--delete` feature, though (as e.g. supported by `rsync` – if someone needs such, maybe give 3rd-party-tools like [better-adb-sync](https://github.com/SelfAdjointOperator/better-adb-sync) a try).

As to permissions, it seems keeping them is not possible. I gladly stand corrected on that point if someone has a solution to it.

¹ **Update:** running a few tests it seems `--sync` is **simply ignored silently** with `adb pull` even if no error is thrown: **newer files on target have been overwritten.** Not sure if implementation is planned, but with r27 (the first version `adb pull` no longer complained `--sync` would be an invalid option) being released in 2018 I'd not place a bet on that. With `push` it works as advertized, though.